# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka - Serde class not found: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde$StringSerde

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am trying to build a simple Kafka Streams application using Spring Cloud Stream framework. I can connect to the stream to push raw data for processing. But when I try to process the stream for event counting by key, I get `Serde class not found: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde$StringSerde` exception when I run the application. I checked in my project included libraries and I could locate the `Serde` class, it's not missing. I am not sure why at run time it is not being loaded!

Below are my source files.

`com.pgp.learn.kafka.analytics.AnalyticsApplication`

```
package com.pgp.learn.kafka.analytics;

import com.pgp.learn.kafka.analytics.model.PageViewEvent;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.*;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(AnalyticsBinding.class)
public class  AnalyticsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AnalyticsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public static class PageViewEventSource implements ApplicationRunner {
        private final MessageChannel pageViewOut;
        private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

        public PageViewEventSource(AnalyticsBinding binding) {
            this.pageViewOut = binding.pageViewsOut();
        }

        @Override
        public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
            List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Peter", "Tom", "Ady", "Nency", "George", "Kevin", "Chelsey", "Thomas");
            List<String> pages = Arrays.asList("About", "Contact", "Blogs", "Gallery", "Music", "Site-map", "News");

            Runnable runner = () -> {
                String rName = names.get(new Random().nextInt(names.size()));
                String rPage = pages.get(new Random().nextInt(pages.size()));

                PageViewEvent event = new PageViewEvent(rName, rPage, Math.random() > .5 ? 10L : 1000L);

                Message<PageViewEvent> message = MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(event)
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, event.getUserId().getBytes())
                        .build();

                try {
                    this.pageViewOut.send(message);
                    log.info("Sent: " + message.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e);
                }
            };

            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class PageViewEventProcessor {
        private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

        @StreamListener
        @SendTo(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_COUNT_OUT)
        public static KStream<String, Long> process(
                @Input(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_VIEW_IN_CHANNEL) KStream<String, PageViewEvent> events) {
            return events
                    .filter((s, pageViewEvent) -> pageViewEvent.getDuration() > 10)
                    .map((s, pageViewEvent) -> new KeyValue<>(pageViewEvent.getPage(), 0L))
                    .groupByKey()
                    //Also tried using below line, but no luck
//.groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))

.count(Materialized.as(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_COUNT_MV))
                    .toStream();
        }
    }
}
```

`com.pgp.learn.kafka.analytics.AnalyticsBinding`

```
package com.pgp.learn.kafka.analytics;

import com.pgp.learn.kafka.analytics.model.PageViewEvent;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

public interface AnalyticsBinding {

    String PAGE_VIEW_OUT_CHANNEL = "pvout";
    String PAGE_VIEW_IN_CHANNEL = "pvin";
    String PAGE_COUNT_MV = "pcmvc";
    String PAGE_COUNT_OUT = "pcout";
    String PAGE_COUNT_IN = "pcin";

    @Input (PAGE_VIEW_IN_CHANNEL)
    KStream<String, PageViewEvent> pageViewsIn();

    @Output (PAGE_VIEW_OUT_CHANNEL)
    MessageChannel pageViewsOut();

    @Output (PAGE_COUNT_OUT)
    KStream<String, Long> pageCountOut();

}
```

`application.properties`

```
# defaults
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.mms=1000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=54.173.206.255
#
# page views out
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pvout.destination=pvs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pvout.producer.header-mode=raw
#
# page views in
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pvin.destination=pvs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pvin.consumer.header-mode=raw
#
# page count out
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcout.destination=pcs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcout.producer.use-native-encoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcout.producer.keySerde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcout.producer.valueSerde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$LongSerde
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pgp.learn.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>analytics</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>analytics</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**Exception while Running**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Serde class not found: 
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.adaptAndRetrieveInboundArguments(KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.java:308) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-2.1.0.RC4.jar:2.1.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.orchestrateStreamListenerSetupMethod(KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-2.1.0.RC4.jar:2.1.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.doPostProcess(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:195) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RC4.jar:2.1.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$0(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:167) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RC4.jar:2.1.0.RC4]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.injectAndPostProcessDependencies(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RC4.jar:2.1.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:105) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RC4.jar:2.1.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.pgp.learn.kafka.analytics.AnalyticsApplication.main(AnalyticsApplication.java:35) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:558) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Serde class not found: 
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KeyValueSerdeResolver.getKeySerde(KeyValueSerdeResolver.java:177) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-2.1.0.RC4.jar:2.1.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KeyValueSerdeResolver.getInboundKeySerde(KeyValueSerdeResolver.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-2.1.0.RC4.jar:2.1.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.adaptAndRetrieveInboundArguments(KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.java:246) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-2.1.0.RC4.jar:2.1.0.RC4]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde$StringSerde
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadClass(Utils.java:333) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:322) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KeyValueSerdeResolver.getKeySerde(KeyValueSerdeResolver.java:171) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-2.1.0.RC4.jar:2.1.0.RC4]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Any help to find what I am doing wrong here? I am new to Kafka and Stream processing. So, please excuse me if I am doing any silly mistake.

Comment: Try adding the base kafka streams dependencies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo in your configuration properties:

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde$StringSerde`

It is missing ***'s'*** in ***Serde***. Should be `...serialization.Serdes$StringSerde`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. After adding 's' to the Serde in default configuration, I stopped getting the exception as listed above. However, now my program stopped recognizing the broker configuration and takes the default configuration with "localhost". Any help to solve that problem now?

Comment: It is hard to say. Perhaps you can post  sample project that reproduces the issue in the GitHub, so we can look.